# Run javascript once per session

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like the code below  to execute only once when the website first loads, as at the moment the script executes every time the index page loads and is therefore showing the div every time the user comes back to the index page from within the site.

NB. I only have the code on the index page.

It would be really helpful is somebody could show me the code I need to paste instead of this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function show(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's your server side technology, e.g. PHP?

Comment: It's less reliable than using server side functionality to do it, but if you need a purely JavaScript solution, I would recommend looking into HTML5's [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Edit: did you mean once per session, like you said, or do you mean just the first time the site is visited?

Comment: Also, the code you posted doesn't show or hide anything - it provides functions that allow you to show/hide elements. I'm guessing the actual code you need to deal with is elsewhere.

Comment: I rather think that "show me the code I need to paste instead of this" implies you should probably hire somebody to do the work for you. This isn't a "do my work for free" site.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick replies, i will take a look at the local storage option. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') &&
    (localStorage.getItem('yourCodeDescription') === null)) {

    // Your code here
    console.log('ok');

    localStorage.setItem('yourCodeDescription', true);
}
```

Try something like this to make use of a localStorage.

Comment: Note: Name/value pairs are always stored as strings - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp